# User-agent Processing in php

Tags: php, user-agent

This is a really simple question, but I want to know how I can use php to simply find the architecture, and the operating system (version too?) with php. I also need to know how to do this behind a reverse proxy.

Thanks,

macintosh264

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

https://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and use this:

$_SERVER[ 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' ]

Comment: Alright, I see that and it gives me: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1. Now how can I parse that into data so I can just see Macintosh and 10.7 and Firefox as unique variables

Comment: The above mentioned get_browser() combined with a browser caps file provides structured infos by means of an assoc. array.

Answer (score 0):

See the [get_browser()](http://php.net/get_browser) function, it can identify platform, browser, and other capabilities.

For users behind a proxy, it is unlikely you can get this information as the user agent will probably be changed and information about the user hidden.

Comment: Don't forget, that get_browser() requires to install a browscap.ini file. caps can be found here: http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp